# Numpad always writing numbers but arrow symbols with AltGr regardless of NumLock state?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, wayland, xkb, numlock

I want to set the numpad so it by always writes digits regardless of the state of NumLock, but it writes arrows and math operators with AltGr.

In GNOME, I can set some options for the keyboard layout in Tweaks at *Mouse and keyboard → Additional layout options*. I am interested in these:

- *Compatibility options → Numeric keypad always enters digits (as in macOS)*, corresponding to the XKB option *numpad:mac*
- *Layout of numeric keypad → Unicode arrows and math operators*, corresponding to the XKB option *keypad:oss*

Each of these options alone does a part of what I want, but, if they are enabled together, the first option (*numpad:mac*) does not work, so the numpad's functions again depend on the state of NumLock, which I would like to avoid.

How can I set the numpad to do that? I use GNOME with Wayland, so things like *localectl* and *setxkbmap* do not work (except in X11 apps), but I expect that the results through them would be the same as described above because the keyboard settings in GNOME follow exactly the XKB settings. I am willing to edit XKB layout files; although I do not have root access, Wayland GNOME supports user-specific XKB configurations AFAIK.

I use a system with Ubuntu 22.04 without root access (school PC). I asked a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1811533/how-can-i-have-numpad-always-writing-numbers-by-default-and-arrows-with-altgr-re) but for a different system. I ask here too because I have the same problem on Ubuntu.